# Glue error importing to DynamoDB from an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

Could anyone tell me why I am getting an error when using Glue to read a very simple exported DynamoDB json file (in S3 bucket) to a new DynamoDB instance. I have looked at the json and it seems fine

Both DynamoDB instances composite key partition key = 'pk' and range key = 'sk' which are strings, its unbelievably simple its just to test it out.

Heres the relevant part of the script

```
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply( 
frame=S3bucket_node1, 
mappings=[ 
("Item.pk.S", "string", "Item.pk.S", "string"), 
("Item.sk.S", "string", "Item.sk.S", "string") ], 
 transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2", 
)

S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options( 
frame=ApplyMapping_node2, 
connection_type="dynamodb", connection_options={"dynamodb.output.tableName": "my-table"}
}
```

But I always get the error when I run the script

WriteDynamicFrame. The provided key element does not match the schema

But both example databases have the same schema , its kind of driving me insane . I don't know how to debug this or resolve it , it seems so straight forward any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You need to change the value of the target table from `Item.pk.S` to `pk`.